# Esri-leaflet-geocoder: Component not rendering; How to connect providers in Production

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet, esri-leaflet-geocoder

I am using the great `esri-leaflet-geocoder` plugin and can't get it to render in production.

I registered for a provider (ArcGIS Online Geocoding Service) and got a api key, and followed the [documentation](https://github.com/Esri/esri-leaflet-geocoder) on the github page to add the api key:

```
var searchControl = L.esri.Geocoding.geosearch({
  providers: [
    L.esri.Geocoding.arcgisOnlineProvider({
      // API Key to be passed to the ArcGIS Online Geocoding Service
      useMapBounds: false,
      apikey: process.env.ESRI_API_KEY
    })
  ]
});
```

I was getting the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'Geocoding' of undefined`

So with that I went to the official documentation page of esri-leaflet-geocoder [here](https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/api-reference/controls/geosearch.html#providers) and tried what was listed there. Turns out it seems more up to date.

```
var provider = ELG.arcgisOnlineProvider({ token: process.env.ESRI_API_KEY });

var searchControl = new ELG.Geosearch({
  useMapBounds: false,
  providers: [provider]
});

console.log('ELG.arcgisOnlineProvider() ', provider);

console.log('searchControl', searchControl);
```

It didn't work but the consoles seems to show that they indeed take the props listed in the documentation:

```
ELG.arcgisOnlineProvider()  
NewClass {_requestQueue: Array(0), _authenticating: false, options: {…}, _initHooksCalled: true, _eventParents: {…}}
options:
supportsSuggest: true
token: process.env.ESRI_API_KEY // In the log it's a string
url: "https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/"
__proto__: Object
_authenticating: false
_eventParents: {1: NewClass}
_initHooksCalled: true
_requestQueue: []
__proto__: NewClass


searchControl 
NewClass {options: {…}, _geosearchCore: NewClass, _leaflet_id: 1, _initHooksCalled: true}
options:
providers: Array(1)
0: NewClass
options: {token: process.env.ESRI_API_KEY // Again it is logging a string
url: "https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/", supportsSuggest: true}
_authenticating: false
_eventParents: {1: NewClass}
_initHooksCalled: true
_requestQueue: []
__proto__: NewClass
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
useMapBounds: false
__proto__: Object
```

So how can I get the 'searchControl' to work/render in Production?

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me:

```js
import * as ELG from "esri-leaflet-geocoder";

var searchControl = ELG.geosearch({
  useMapBounds: false,
  providers: [
    ELG.arcgisOnlineProvider({
      apikey: "your key here"
    })
  ]
});

searchControl.addTo(leafletMap);
```

### [Working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-breeze-kgt95?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: Thank you Seth I'll give it a try!